# Python 3.6 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx

I have absolutely no idea what can be the problem. I did the pip installer (pip install pyttsx3) and re-installed the JetBrains PyCharm, but it still not working.

Comment: It depends on which version of Python your Pycharm is set and on which version of Python you installed the module.  
Go to `File -> Settings -> Project:.. -> Project Interpreter` and check which version of Python you run on the project. Then go to the CMD/ terminal and write `pip -V` and it will tell you the pip version and the Python one.  
Might be different version.

Comment: Yes, the pip version is different. In Pycharm it is 10.0.1, and the other is 18.0. So how can I fix it? How can I upgrade the pip inside Pycharm?

Comment: Wasn't talking about pip itself but rather about the Python version. At the end of `pip -V` it should write the Python version. To upgrade pip you can use `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, the the python version is 3.6 in Pycharm and in the cmd.  So it is the same

Comment: Hmm, you might have multiple of the same interpreter. When you install Pycharm you have the option to also install Python. Check if you have multiple of the same Python in `File -> Settings -> Project:.. -> Project Interpreter`. Click on the arrow at "Python Interpreter". If you only have one then try to first reinstall the package using `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyttsx3`.
If none of these work then I suggest to try and install the package on Pycharm itself by clicking on the green plus sign at the project interpreter window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a pyCharm terminal window, then install 'pipenv' which is an improved pip replacement as follows:

`pip install -u pipenv`

Then use pipenv instead of pip as this will create it's own Pipfile and virtualenv. You can install pyttsx3 as follows:

`pipenv install pyttsx3`

This will create a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock which pycharm should pickup and ensure it's using the correct python version and virtualenv environment. Otherwise check that your python interpreter is set correctly in "Run/Debug configurations". If it's not in that list then you can add a new python interpreter via the Preferences->Project->Project Interpreter option.

Answer (score 2):

Well i might be a little late but incase anyone is still having problem, i managed to fix it with `py -m pip install pyttsx3`

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution on my mac with BigSur OS, maybe because i have a mixed [configuration](https://dev.to/v3frankie/setup-your-mac-for-development-2020-edition-1c8a)

so i try pip3 install pyttsx3 and instales but checkin in different place:

when import fails throwing an error. So i decided to go on and i found where the pip3 installed the pkgs:

check if is installed:

```
python3 -m pyttsx3                        
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named pyttsx3

python -m pyttsx3 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pyttsx3

pip3 install pyttsx3
```

first check where is a previus version:

```
ls -lstr /Users/paul/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
...
 0 drwxr-xr-x   8 paul  staff     256 Mar  2 01:52 pyobjc-7.1.dist-info
  0 drwxr-xr-x   9 paul  staff     288 Mar  2 01:52 pyttsx3
  0 drwxr-xr-x   9 paul  staff     288 Mar  2 01:52 pyttsx3-2.90.dist-info
  0 drwxr-xr-x  17 paul  staff     544 Mar  2 02:44 urllib3
  0 drwxr-xr-x   8 paul  staff     256 Mar  2 02:44 urllib3-1.26.3.dist-info
  0 drwxr-xr-x   9 paul  staff     288 Mar  2 02:44 soupsieve
  0 drwxr-xr-x   8 paul  staff     256 Mar  2 02:44 soupsieve-2.2.dist-info
  8 -rw-r--r--   1 paul  staff     544 Mar  2 02:44 rubicon_
...



python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

check the path of the pkg on your system with:

```
python -m pyttsx3
```

Then you just have to copy to the path where you need to use the package.

```
sudo cp -r /Users/paul/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyttsx3/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

sudo cp -r /Users/paul/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyttsx3-2.90.dist-info /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

All I did is used '`python <filename>`' to run the program instead of '`python3 <filename>`' and it WORKED.

I am not sure, but maybe pyttsx3 does not support the python3 syntax to find itself.

I hope this helps anyone out there, who searched for hours just like me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3 then use

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you're intending to answer to old question (this one is over 2 year old): Please check if the question already has an accepted answer (that's the case here). If so, please only answer if you really have a substantial improvement to offer.